# how to recover files delted using "find /export/reports -mtime +112 -type f -delete"

Tags: linux

I wanted to delete .pdf files, i used "find /export/reports -mtime +112 -type f -delete", however i did not applied any filter for .pdf file and end up deleting required files as well.

Can any one please help me with how to recover them?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

1. Use debugfs to view a filesystems log

> ```
>  $ debugfs -w /dev/mapper/wks01-root
> ```

2. At the debugfs prompt

> `debugfs: lsdel`

3. Sample output

> Inode  Owner  Mode    Size    Blocks   Time deleted
>
> ```
> 23601299      0 120777      3    1/   1 Tue Mar 13 16:17:30 2012
>
> 7536655      0 120777      3    1/   1 Tue May  1 06:21:22 2012
>
> 2 deleted inodes found.
> ```

4. Run the command in debugfs

> `debugfs: logdump -i <7536655>`
> 5) Determine files inode

```
> ... ... .... output truncated
    >     Fast_link_dest: bin
    >     Blocks:  (0+1): 7235938   FS block 7536642 logged at sequence 38402086, journal block 26711
    >     (inode block for inode 7536655):
    >     Inode: 7536655   Type: symlink        Mode:  0777   Flags: 0x0   Generation: 3532221116
    >     User:     0   Group:     0   Size: 3
    >     File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
    >     Links: 0   Blockcount: 0
    >     Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
    >     ctime: 0x4f9fc732 -- Tue May  1 06:21:22 2012
    >     atime: 0x4f9fc730 -- Tue May  1 06:21:20 2012
    >     mtime: 0x4f9fc72f -- Tue May  1 06:21:19 2012
    >     dtime: 0x4f9fc732 -- Tue May  1 06:21:22 2012
    >     Fast_link_dest: bin
    >     Blocks:  (0+1): 7235938 No magic number at block 28053: end of journal.
```

6. With the above inode info run the following commands

   > dd if=/dev/mapper/wks01-root of=recovered.file.001 bs=4096 count=1
   > skip=7235938 file recovered.file.001 file: ASCII text, with very long
   > lines

Files been recovered to recovered.file.001.

there are also some tools which can be helpful:

**Recovery Tools - Command Line :**
testdisk,
photorec,
extundelete

**Recovery Tools - Gui :**
R-Linux,
R-Studio,
UFS Explorer,
Recovery Explorer